# USB flash drive not working

Tags: usb, flash, format

I have a problem with my flash drive. When I plug it in it shows like this:

[image]

And when I try to format it, it says it has "Unknown capacity":

[image]

Do you know any way I can fix this or any software that can help me with this problem?

Comment: Can you read or write anything to it? This will most likely be closed as it is asking for directions to a program.

Comment: @Xavierjazz No, when I double click it it says "Please insert a disk into Removable Disk (G:)". But when I unplug the device the icon is gone. And the PC is making the sounds both when i plug or unplug the device. So... Is it lost cause, or can I do anything about it?

Comment: Open *Disk Management* (I *think* that's `diskmgmt.msc`). Post a screenshot that shows how it reports the relevant physical device. Also include the make, model and specified size of the drive, to the best of your ability.

Comment: @Xavierjazz We don't auto-close just because a question allows for a solution involving third-party software. This question has a reasonably clear problem statement IMO (though it could definitely benefit from a few more details) and is asking **how to solve that,** so should be fine. Generally speaking, if editing out "please suggest some tool to fix this" would leave the essence of the question unchanged (as it would in this case; OP would still be asking for a way to regain access to the thumb drive), then it's not a software recommendation question. At least, that's my rule of thumb. :)

Comment: I wasn't sure, hence no vote to close. Thanks for the comment.