# USB Drive Not Working

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

I have a problem with my 16GB Lexar USB flash drive, similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/927525/usb-flash-drive-not-working).

I was trying to use the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool to install a Windows 10 installer onto it, but the installer failed multiple times with the error code `0x80042405 - 0xa001a`,  which I believe is a common error (I found information [here](https://appuals.com/fix-media-creation-tool-error-0x80042405-0xa001a/IOf)).

I tried to convert the partition layout to MBR (as the guide said), but I guess I didn't know what would happen to the drive.

Now, when I plug the drive in, it says to `Insert a drive into E:`. I tried to `clean` the drive and convert it back to GPT format, but still the same. I can't even format it!

Comment: Download the ISO file, use Rufus to create a bootable media. It is more configurable and takes care of other important parameters automatically.

Comment: I actually did just use Rufus, and it created a second partition on the drive, where it installed Windows.

Comment: "I tried to convert the partition layout to MB" - If you are trying to install Windows 10, then converting the partition layout to MBR, is going to make it impossible to boot to it unless you enable Legacy mode.  This will also require the HDD, Windows will be installed to, to be MBR not GPT.  Your log which should be contained in your question, instead of answer, indicates the drive is also being detected as a USB 2 device instead of a USB 3 device.  You have not currently provided enough information to identify the source of your problems.

Comment: Rufus Log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fml_csiVVXyFfLhsqgoB9tWgZ6hCSIwr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I know, I made a horrible mistake. I don't really know what other information to provide, if you would like, you can ask me for something, and I will try my best to find it.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have another flash drive, that is a known-good drive, that you could insert into the usb port?  If so, does the system recognize it?

If not, the problem may be internal RAM.  Not that RAM is bad, it could be that the internal RAM sticks need to be reseated and this can be done without paying $$ for the job.  Will explain how to reseat the ram if it is needed.

Comment: The USB port seems to be working fine.

Comment: Although, something weird I've found is- all devices I plug into my computer make the "Network Locations" disappear, and the drive only shows up in Disk Management, but not under the list of drives. I have another MBR drive with the same story, but it's an SD card.

Answer (score -1):

The ISO may only be sized enough to contain only the files in the image and thus making it a read only file after the iso image is *burned* (or written to) the flash drive.  And note, the size of the flash drive would also be deminished to the size of the iso.  As to why it's not being recognized I have no immediate answer.  Do you have the program DEVCON ?   If so, devcon status usb*  might help find out what's going on for connected USB devices.  Here is the link about devcon:
[Quick Method to install DevCon.exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/1002950/quick-method-to-install-devcon-exe)

Comment: A command prompt window opens, but instantly closes. Is that right?